# Asynchronous Server-Side TCP/IP

Tags: c#, tcp

I saw just what I needed at msdn to create my TCP server,but there are missing parts in the code.

[>Here's<](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y709t3b.aspx) the article and here's the code:

```
// This server waits for a connection and then uses asynchronous operations to
// accept the connection with initial data sent from the client.

// Establish the local endpoint for the socket.

IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

// Create a TCP/IP socket.
Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );

// Bind the socket to the local endpoint, and listen for incoming connections.
listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
listener.Listen(100);

while (true) 
{
    // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
    allDone.Reset();

    // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections and receive data from the client.
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");

    // Accept the connection and receive the first 10 bytes of data. 
    // BeginAccept() creates the accepted socket.
    int receivedDataSize = 10;
    listener.BeginAccept(null, receivedDataSize, new AsyncCallback(AcceptReceiveDataCallback), listener);

    // Wait until a connection is made and processed before continuing.
    allDone.WaitOne();
}
}



public static void AcceptReceiveDataCallback(IAsyncResult ar) 
{
// Get the socket that handles the client request.
Socket listener = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;

// End the operation and display the received data on the console.
byte[] Buffer;
int bytesTransferred;
Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(out Buffer, out bytesTransferred, ar);
string stringTransferred = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Buffer, 0, bytesTransferred);

Console.WriteLine(stringTransferred);
Console.WriteLine("Size of data transferred is {0}", bytesTransferred);

// Create the state object for the asynchronous receive.
StateObject state = new StateObject();
state.workSocket = handler;
handler.BeginReceive( state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
}
```

"event allDone" is missing,how do I make a similiar one so it will wait for a connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) type has nothing to do with events (such as a Click event on a control). They both happen to have the word "Event" in the name.

See [Asynchronous Server Socket Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

allDone is a ManualResetEvent.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx

-Oisin

Comment: You can declare a ManualResetEvent like:

ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);